# Sequence goes to 3 and the number of elements make it 3 and not 3 is infinite

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find a sequence {yn} such that yn → 3 and the sets {n : yn = 3} and{n : yn ≠ 3} are both infinite ( so n is in positive integers)

Thanks in advance! I had trouble setting up the sequence to have one of the sets have infinite elements.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_{2n}=3+\frac1n$, and $y_{2n+1}=3$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$y_n = 3 + \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^2}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Form your sequence by alternating the terms of two suitably chosen sequences.